# Check if a code exists in Django Database

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'am trying to check if a value exists in one of my database fields
so this is my `models.py`

```
class Student(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='نام کاربری')
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, validators=[MinLengthValidator(10)], blank=True, verbose_name='کد ملی')
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        super(Student, self).__str__()
        return self.username
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'دانش آموز'
        verbose_name_plural = 'دانش آموزان'
```

I can create a model in django's panel but the thing that I want, is Checking if a property of this class exists

this is my `views.py`

```
class LoginView(View):
    def get(self: Self, request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
        login_form: LoginForm = LoginForm()
        return render(
            request=request,
            template_name='index.html',
            context={
                'login_form': login_form,
            }
        )
    
    def post(self: Self, request: HttpRequest) -> Union[HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponsePermanentRedirect, None]:
        login_form: LoginForm = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
        if (login_form.is_valid()):
            username = login_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            code = login_form.cleaned_data.get('code')
            
            # I want to check if " code " is in database
            # if it exists, login
            # else show an error
```

I want to check if the `code` variable value, exists in my database
and if it exists, login
else show an error

I expect my code check the value existance
but I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1):

You can check with:

```
class LoginView(View):
    # …

    def post(
        self: Self, request: HttpRequest
    ) -> Union[HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponsePermanentRedirect, None]:
        login_form: LoginForm = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            username = login_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            code = login_form.cleaned_data.get('code')
            try:
                student = Student.objects.get(code=code)
                # student exists
            except Student.DoesNotExist:
                # no such student
                pass
```

since the `code` is not unique, and even can be NULL, it is however possible that *multiple* such students exist as well.

---

> **Note**: Subclassing the `View` class directly is often *not* necessary. In this case your view looks like a [**`FormView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView). By using a `FormView` instead of a simple `View`, you often do not have to implement a lot of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 1):

to login a user you should check both of code and user name:

```
try:
    student = Student.objects.get(code=code, username=username)
    # authenticate user
except Student.DoesNotExist:
    # raise error
```